# merge Array of objects into array with unique object

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a array of various object, but I need turn this objects into unique object. Below I share my code.

```
$result = [];
$idiomas = Idioma::all()->toArray();

foreach ($idiomas as $lang) {
    $result[] =  [
      $lang['palavra_chave'] => $lang[$id]
    ];
}

return response()->json($result);
```

reponse

```
[
  { "INICIAL": "Inicial"},{ "RELATORIOS": "Relatórios"},{ "FUNCIONARIO": "Funcionário"},{ "DATA": "Data"},{ "ANEXAR_IMAGEM": "Anexar imagem"},{ "DISCIPLINA": "Disciplina"}
]
```

But I need transform this objects into one, like this

```
[
    {
        "INICIAL": "Inicial",
        "RELATORIOS": "Relatórios",
        "FUNCIONARIO": "Funcionário",
        "DATA": "Data",
        "ANEXAR_IMAGEM": "Anexar imagem",
        "DISCIPLINA": "Disciplina"
    }
]
```

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$idiomas = Idioma::all()->toArray();

if (count($idiomas)) {
    //$result = new stdClass; # wouldn't work without base namespace
    $result = new \stdClass;
    foreach ($idiomas as $lang) {
        $result->{$lang['palavra_chave']} = $lang[$id];
    }
    return response()->json([$result]);
}

// otherwise
```

Comment: Thank you. Just to remember, in Laravel you must either write`$o = new \stdClass()`  or add a use statement on the top of the file.

Comment: @PaulinhoRodrigues Just checked in some code here. You are quite right, I mean I used backslash there. Editing.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** @Tpojka's answer definitely looks more appropriate. Use the following one only if you can't change the way you retrieve data initially (I'm not familiar enough with Laravel).

The following should work:

```
// Take your initial JSON
$input = <<<JSON
[
  { "INICIAL": "Inicial"},{ "RELATORIOS": "Relatórios"},{ "FUNCIONARIO": "Funcionário"},{ "DATA": "Data"},{ "ANEXAR_IMAGEM": "Anexar imagem"},{ "DISCIPLINA": "Disciplina"}
]
JSON;

// Transform it into a PHP array
$input_as_array = json_decode($input);

// Reduce it into an associative array
$associative_array = array_reduce($input_as_array, function($associative_array, $item) {
    return $associative_array += (array)$item;
}, []);

// Encode it back into JSON, as an array
$result = json_encode([$associative_array], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```